# How do I protect embedded fonts from being downloaded from my website?

Tags: fonts, font-face, embedding

I am wondering how would I protect my fonts that I made from being downloaded if I use `@font-face` or another method for font-embedding?

Answer (score 3):

stick them in a folder with a .htaccess file in the root?

Comment: So I can use this and not have to worry about people stealing my fonts embedding using @font-face

Comment: your fonts are just a file. so if someone types in example.com/hiddenfonts/mysecretfont.ttf then they're going to hit a login box

Answer (score 0):

If you use [cufón](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/), you can set it to tie the fonts to a specific domain, which is recommended. That way the created JS file won't work anywhere else other than on your domain.